# PHP return doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans, debian, phalcon

We ran into a mind boggling issue today..
Code is written in PHP 5.6 on Phalcon framework. My colleague can't run my code because when I write `return` from a controller action method (meant for Ajax request) he gets a whole view instead of the json object I try to return.
However, when we use `die()` or `exit()` (which doesn't return to the caller as `return` does but in the action method it doesn't matter) everything gets returned as intended.
Also I am running Debian 8.8, he's running Ubuntu. Both of us are using NetBeans 8.2

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Code works perfectly on my machine. For example `public function testAction() { return json_encode('some stuff'); }` won't return the object for Ajax request on my colleagues machine. It would return the whole view.

Comment: netbeans is your IDE and is irrelevant when you actually _run_ the code.

Comment: Irrelevant even on different OSs?

Comment: Open this issue on Phalcon forum https://forum.phalconphp.com and we'll get it sorted for sure (the community)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `die()` or `exit()`, everything is stopped.

From PHP manual :

```
(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
exit — Output a message and terminate the current script
```

This includes the framework. It sounds like you might have did something like echo out the json and expect it to output only the json. I have not used Phalcon but many frameworks have their own series of functions and scripts to go through before a page is rendered. Therefore by calling return, the framework's script was put to work, to construct a full view and outputting to the browser, your JSON might have been buried somewhere inside.

On the other hand, by calling `exit()`, everything stops right there and no more rendering functions from the framework will run.

Learn your framework and adapt, hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .The framework is not the issue, compatibility is though. I am not entirely sure the framework is to blame as it works on my machine just well.